# why the background image of the following code does not show up?

Tags: css

```
body{font-family:Georgia;background-image:url('https://content.codecademy.com/courses/learn-css-selectors-visual-rules/hypnotize_bg.png'); }
.header{background-color:blue;text-align:center;}
.about-me{font-size:20px;opacity:0.5;}
.title{font-weight:bold;}
h1{color:azure;}
```

I was expecting the image to cover the background...

Comment: Please share your `html` structure as well. So that other users can see why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

https://content.codecademy.com/courses/learn-css-selectors-visual-rules/hypnotize_bg.png is a blank image. If you just try to go to this URL it's a plain white box.

Comment: This should be a comment